# How to use Poisson distribution on this task

Tags: poisson-distribution

The ferry crosses the strait from beach A to beach B at regular intervals of 20 minutes. The ferry has room for 7 cars.

Suppose no cars left behind when ferry first leave. Suppose the number of cars arriving on the beach A the next 20 minutes in the following cases is the Poisson distribution parameter 6.

What is the probability that the ferry will be full the next time it leaves at beach A?

Should i use poisson distribution and is lambda on this case the 6?

[image: Poisson distribute]

Comment: Yes you can use the Poisson distribution with $\lambda=6$, though I would say this could tell you how likely the ferry is to be full when it next *leaves* beach $A$ rather than when it arrives

Comment: Yes you are right i made mistake it should be when it next leaves the beach. Should i use the normal poisson distribution?

Comment: That would work, so long as you look at the correct probability

Comment: Is there any examples what formula i need to use i can't get the right answer with anything?

Comment: What do you think is the correct answer and how did you calculate it?

Comment: I tried to calculate it with poisson distribute formula and i get 0.104 but that's not right. I added the formula to the original post.

Comment: You seem to have calculated the probability for $k=8$. I would have thought you need to consider $k \ge 7$. This might suggest an infinite sum, so an alternative calculation is $1$ minus the probability the number is $k=0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$ or $6$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\geqslant 7) &= 1-\mathbb P(X<6)\\ &= 1-\sum_{k=0}^6 \mathbb P(X=k)\\ &= 1-\sum _{k=0}^6 \frac{6^k}{k!}e^{-6}\\
&=1-\frac{1223}{5}e^{-6}\approx 0.3936972.
\end{align}